# flutter: change default Icon text color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I modified textTheme  theme data on my application :

```
  ThemeData get lightTheme => ThemeData(
        disabledColor: AppColors.disabled,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.paper,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          button: AppTextStyles.button,
          overline: AppTextStyles.overline,
        ),
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppSize.s32),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
          (final states) => states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
              ? 50.gray
              : 500.primary,
        ),
 
      ),
    ),
```

I Used this code too but not worked:

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
      RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppSize.s32),
      ),
    ),
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (final states) => states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
          ? 50.gray
          : 500.primary,
    ),
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (final states) {
        return const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF661F1F));
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

This is `AppTextStyles.button,`:

```
  static final TextStyle _base = GoogleFonts.inder(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  );
  static final button = _base.copyWith(
      fontSize: 16.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.black);
```

But when I added `ElevatedButton` the text color is still white?

```
      ElevatedButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
          label: Text("Sign in")),
```

This is my material:

```
GetMaterialApp(
          theme: AppThemes().lightTheme,
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a complete runnable code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the foregroundColor property of the ButtonStyle.
`foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)`

Comment: It's working, then What is the `button TextThem` If is not working? and why fontSize or fontWeight work but color not?  @Burnny Kibonge

Comment: {MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? foregroundColor}
The color for the button's [Text] and [Icon] widget descendants.

This color is typically used instead of the color of the [textStyle]. All of the components that compute defaults from [ButtonStyle] values compute a default [foregroundColor] and use that instead of the [textStyle]'s color.

Answer (score 0):

try change color in `foregroundColor` inside `ButtonStyle`.

```
foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (final states) => states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
                ? Colors.grey
                : Color(0xFF661F1F),
```

Comment: I did before and It didn't work @Hadi

Comment: edited the code, try this one.